# min-height inside a flex item is being ignored in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a flex container with `flex-direction: row` and some flex items. The flex items, on their own would have various heights, but because of the default `align-items: stretch`, they all fill the flex containers height. In my specific use case, this is perfect.

The issue is that I have these `<div>`s inside each flex container and I need them to take up the full height of their parent. I thought I could just set `min-height: 100%` on them. This solution works on both Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not on Google Chrome for some reason.

Here's a code snippet demonstrating the problem. If you view this on chrome, you will see that the shorter white `.card` is not filling up the purple `.card_container`. if you view this on IE or FF however, it will fill up the parent container's height.

```css
#grid {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;      
}

.card_container {
  width: 300px; 
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}


.card {
  background: white;
  min-height: 100%;    /* <- Why isn't this working? */
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      This text is very short.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One work around I have found is to make `.card_container` a flex container as well and to explicitly set the `.card` to `width: 100%`.

For example, the snippet below seems to work in Chrome, FF and IE:

```css
#grid {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;

  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   
}

.card_container {
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}


.card {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      This text is very short.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <div class="card">
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
      This text is very long. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering why this work around is necessary though. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Does anyone know if it is documented anywhere?